# What is the name of this schematic, and what it is used for?

Tags: digital-logic, cmos, buffer, schematic

I've got this schematic of a device I need some information about.  It it was in electronics class I had, but I do not know the name of the schematic.

The problem is, I can pretty much see what it does, it buffers the DataOut signal, when the Enable pin is HIGH, but why do we need the PullUpEnable, and shouldn't it be "PullUpDisable", sice we stop pulling up when it is HIGH.

Can someone tell me if he/she has used this device, or if you know the name of the device and where it is used, so I can make a further google research?

[image]

Comment: That's not a diagram of a specific device.  That's a diagram of a type of circuit.

Comment: So, what are your initial impressions or deductions about this circuit ?

Comment: You're likely to find a whole bunch of those circuit blocks in one single device - probably one for each I**O** pin.

Comment: Sorry, my title is a bit missleading, I need the name of the schematic, so I can research it, see what it does and  where it is used for, so if you know it's name or what it does, feel free to help out :)

Comment: So you're relying on our experience to recognize that circuit? Is that the goal of your class, I mean, just ask the experts? Or are you supposed to make your own reasoning what the circuit could be used for based on the schematic and the names of the signals? If I were your teacher I and you said it is an output buffer, I would ask: **"Why do you that is so?"** Can you then answer something different than: "The experts at SEEE said so."?

Comment: If I were your teacher I'd rather have my students come up with weird and wonderful **but completely wrong** answers as long as they had a good story (a good explanation)  with their answer. *...see what it does...* If you know how a MOSFET can be switched on/off you're already close to figuring out what this circuit does.

Answer (score 8):

That looks like a tristate-capable output buffer, as used on the output pins of various microcontrollers. It can be set to output a value, disabled (floating/tristate), or to have  weak active pullup.

Comment: Ah, that is very good. I think the teacher would give full marks. You remind me ages ago I graduated from a technical college with an EE diploma, and earned my living as a technician, troubleshoot semiconductor testing machines. In those days the schematic is a big blue print sheet of paper, with perhaps one hundred logic gates forming a bowl of spagetti, ... and of course there were no hint labels like enable, pull up, data out etc. I usually gave up after a while and went home to sleep. But some of my team mates would not sleep, and once he had an eraka and got so excited, / cont

Comment: jumped out of bed, 3 am in the morning, took a taxi back to the factory to verify if his guess was correct. I guess my team mate saw electronic troubleshooting as playing chess. Ah, bed time, call it a day.